# Incrementar un numero dentro de un condicional en python

Tags: python

Muy buenas, soy nuevo en esto y me gustaria saber como puedo hacer un incremento de un numero en una condicional, y a su vez dentro de un input.
Ex: hay 3 preguntas y si responde SI, se incrementa el valor en un numero empezando desde 0  asi hasta completar las 3 preguntas.
Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

grande = input ( 'Eres Alto?:  \r\n' )

numero=0

if grande == 'SI':

```
print([numero]+=1)
```

else:

```
print(numero)
```

Comment: estas imprimiendo el numero mas no asignando el nuevo valor seria `numero +=1` que es igual a decir `numero = numero +1`

Comment: numero=0

if grande == 'SI':

    print(numero =+1)
else:

    print(numero

Me sigue saliendo error, en particular este error: ine 13, in <module>
    print(numero =+1)
TypeError: 'numero' is an invalid keyword argument for print()

Comment: Muchas gracias Bryro

Answer (score 0):

En vez de colocar esto:

`print([numero]+=1)`

Coloca esto dentro del `if`:

```
numero += 1
print(numero)
```

Saludos.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Patricio

Comment: Si muestras el código completo evitas cualquier error de interpretación respecto a la solución.

Comment: Lo hice así porque seguramente era una tarea, para no darle todo 100% listo, espero que se entienda